# Envers RevisionEntity can not be saved with Metadata

Tags: hibernate, playframework-2.0, hibernate-envers

I have a Application written in the Play Framework with Hibernate. I want to add Versioning with the Envers Library.

I have a User Class.

```
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag=true)
public class User
```

A Controller to change some things about the User.

```
@Transactional
public static Result updateAccountStates(Long userId) {
    User user = JPA.em().find(User.class, userId);
    Integer prevStatus = user.status;
    Form<AccountStateForm> form = Form.form(AccountStateForm.class).bindFromRequest();
    form.get().applyTo(user);
    return redirect(routes.Customers.account(userId));
}
```

I want to add to Metadata about who changed the Users Data.

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(UserRevisionListener.class)
public class UserRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    public Staff staff;
}

public class UserRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {
    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {

        UserRevisionEntity userEntity = (UserRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
        userEntity = SecurityUtils.getStaff(ctx());
    }
}
```

Every time the User changes I record witch Staff Member who changed it.

I have added the UserRevisionEntity Model to the persistence.xml:

```
<class>models.UserRevisionEntity</class>
```

When I change the User Status I get:

```
[error] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`creditgate24`.`user_aud`, CONSTRAINT `FK_97pph94d4cb7qah5aygmmll2y` FOREIGN KEY (`REV`) REFERENCES `REVINFO` (`REV`))
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
[error] application - 

! @6mjac6klf - Internal server error, for (POST) [/customers/9/account?csrfToken=fe225b185b9c5ee9f48d58180d0885ca7118d7fd-1435656024963-c42071a398c0e4c84c7682d0] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.11.4.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:111) ~[play-java-jpa_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at controllers.admin.Customers.updateAccountStates(Customers.java:86) ~[classes/:na]
    at admin.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$21$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(routes_routing.scala:952) ~[classes/:na]
    at admin.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$21$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(routes_routing.scala:952) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(Router.scala:264) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:141) ~[play-java-jpa_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:104) ~[play-java-jpa_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at controllers.admin.Customers.updateAccountStates(Customers.java:86) ~[classes/:na]
    at admin.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$21$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(routes_routing.scala:952) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:141) ~[play-java-jpa_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:104) ~[play-java-jpa_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cg`.`user_aud`, CONSTRAINT `FK_97pph94d4cb7qah5aygmmll2y` FOREIGN KEY (`REV`) REFERENCES `REVINFO` (`REV`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
```

It seams that because the the REV entry is not created correctly it is not able to create the User revision.

I don't understand why that is. Seams that this would happen when 'newRevision' throws an Exception, put it should not.

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Do you get any exception?

Comment: Sry, I don't know why I did not add this from the start.

Comment: Can you try logging what data are you trying to persist and what's the contraint that fails?